# Hibernate insert record which does not have primary key

Tags: hibernate

Usually we persist object in DB which had Primary key. At time of insertion PK(primary key) can be identified with "generator" class for @ID attribute. As per my understanding in hibernate we can insert records in table which had primary key. 
What possible way is there if we have to insert in table which does not have any primary key because for persisting any entity we need to specify any of attribute as PK of that Entity

Comment: can you add an example? How is your table, which data are you putting in?

Comment: Leviand  may be we can have Entity - Salary(digit, designation) it doesnot have any primary key and we need to insert new record in table : (10, Admin)

Comment: I don't get the problem then: what if you just `save()` that entity to database ? You got exceptions ?

Comment: yes while saving entity(which doesnt have primary key) I am facing some SQL violations exception. I apologize but cannot paste code here :(

Comment: whitout knowing the error it's impossible helping you :/